# Rename file in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, csv, file-rename

I have the following code, it is not doing what I want it to do. Can anyone help?
This is a timer event project. The application is collecting value and writing it to the .csv file.

This is what I am trying to do:

- If .txt file is missing, rename the .csv as .txt
- rename .csv as .txt,(Whenever .txt file is missing rename .csv as txt)--> this is not working
- If .csv is missing create new one and continue to append to it--> this is working

  ```
          Try

              'Check for .csv file
              If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(csv_File) = False Then
              Else 'if file does not exist, create new file to start writing to it

                  My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(csv_File, vbCrLf & Today & "," & Tag_name_Read & "," & itemValues(0).Value.ToString, True)
              End If



              If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(txt_File) = False Then
                  FileOpen(1, csv_File, OpenMode.Output)
                  FileClose(1)
                  'Check for .txt
                  If File.Exists(txt_File) = False Then
                      ' Change ".CSV" to the path and filename for the file that

                      My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(csv_File, txt_File)
                  End If

              End If


          Catch ex As Exception

          End Try
  ```

Comment: What is it doing?

Comment: It is not renaming the .csv file

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense....what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are having this problem in the future, here is what I did to solve this problem: 
I hope this help

```
            Try

                'Check for .csv file
                If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(csv_File) = False Then
                Else
                    'if file does not exist, create new file to start writing to it
                    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(csv_File, vbCrLf & Today & "," & Tag_name_Read & "," & itemValues(0).Value.ToString, True)

                    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(txt_File) = False Then
                        FileClose()
                      ' Change ".CSV" to the path and filename for the file that you want to rename
                        My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(csv_File, txt_File)
                      'File Header
                        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(csv_File, "Date and Time, Tag Name, Value", False)
                       'Append file
                        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(csv_File, vbCrLf & Today & "," & Tag_name_Read & "," & itemValues(0).Value.ToString, True)
                    End If
                End If


            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
If not io.file.exists(csv_file) then

Using strw as new io.streamwriter(csv_file)

Strw.write(vbCrLf & Today & "," & Tag_name_Read & "," & itemValues(0).Value.ToString)

Strw.close()

End using

End if


If not io.file.exists(txt_file) then

Io.file.move(csv_file,txt_file)

End if
```